# Conversion of NSString in JSON format to NSArray fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

Sorry to post yet another question on converting to NSArray, but I can't get this to work even after reading dozens of posts on the same issue. Seems really easy, but...

```
- (void) parseList : (NSString *) str {

    NSLog(@"list as a string: %@", str);

    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (!data) NSLog(@"no data");

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

    NSLog(@"count: %lu", (unsigned long)[arr count]);
}
```

This is the output:

> list as a string: [{"id":"1","name":"example
>   name","filename":"image.png"}]
> count: 0

How can the array count be 0? There is clearly one item in the array.

I don't want to needlessly complicate this post, but this could be important, so here goes. The string that gets passed into this function is returned by a server in an encrypted format. So before it gets passed in here, it first goes through a decryption process that looks like this:

```
- (NSString *) decryptBase64EncodedString : (NSString *) base64EncodedCipherTextString
                    base64EncodedIvString : (NSString *) base64IvString
{

    NSData *cipherData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64EncodedCipherTextString options:0];
    NSData *ivData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64IvString options:0];

    NSData *data = [self AES128Operation : kCCDecrypt
                          cipherTextData : cipherData
                                  ivData : ivData];

    NSString *decrypted = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return decrypted;
}
```

I don't think that the internals of this function matter so much, other than possibly the last two lines that point out how this string is instantiated (from NSData). It may be neither here nor there, but the main conversion to NSArray seems so straightforward that there must be something more going on here. (if it isn't clear, the string 'decrypted' is what is passed in to 'parseList')

Comment: In the first block of code you posted, `arr` is `nil`. In that case, log `err` so you can see what the problem is.

Comment: You're right. Can't believe I didn't notice that. The error is this: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.)`. There must be some non-printable characters in there somehow. Now how to identify and remove them...

Comment: Sorry, brainfart. Arrays use square brackets in JSON. Never mind.

Comment: `NSLog(@"data: %@", data);`, there may be some trailing bytes that don't show up in `str`. The details of `AES128Operation` may well be important, how is the padding done, are the key and iv the correct length, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured this out. With full credit to @rmmaddy, I realized that my array was nil. When I added an `NSLog` statement to examine the error, I found this:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.)

I discovered that there is at least one null terminating character in the JSON string that needed to be removed before I attempted to parse it. I added this line:

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@""];
```

to the start of my method. It's a little bit hacky, but what can you do?

For completeness, here is the complete method that successfully parses the JSON string:

```
- (void) parseList : (NSString *) str {
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"list as a string: %@", str);

    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (!data) NSLog(@"no data");

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

    if (!arr) NSLog("%@", err);

    NSLog(@"count: %lu", (unsigned long)[arr count]);
}
```

And my output remains the same except that the array count is now 1, as is it should be, and now I can continue on to actually parse out the various elements of the JSON array. I hope this helps somebody.